# Change td data using jquery slider on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have to display a table as 5x5 grid. But the data which I have as json data can have more than 5 columns of data.

Using jquery slider, how to change the data of the table > td based on the slider scroll.

i have the following json object:

```
var tData = [
    ["R1C1","R1C2","R1C3","R1C4","R1C5","R1C6","R1C7","R1C8","R1C9"],
    ["R2C1","R2C2","R2C3","R2C4","R2C5","R2C6","R2C7","R2C8","R2C9"],
    ["R3C1","R3C2","R3C3","R3C4","R3C5","R3C6","R3C7","R3C8","R3C9"],
    ["R4C1","R4C2","R4C3","R4C4","R4C5","R4C6","R4C7","R4C8","R4C9"],
    ["R5C1","R5C2","R5C3","R5C4","R5C5","R5C6","R5C7","R5C8","R5C9"]
];
```

by default the data looks like the below table.

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ 
| R1C1 | R1C2 | R1C3 | R1C4 | R1C5 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |
| R2C1 | R2C2 | R2C3 | R2C4 | R2C5 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |
| R3C1 | R3C2 | R3C3 | R3C4 | R3C5 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |
| R4C1 | R4C2 | R4C3 | R4C4 | R4C5 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |
| R5C1 | R5C2 | R5C3 | R5C4 | R5C5 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ __|
```

on the slider scroll, the data has to be changed like the below.

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ 
| R1C2 | R1C3 | R1C4 | R1C5 | R1C6 |
| _ _ _|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ |
| R2C2 | R2C3 | R2C4 | R2C5 | R2C6 |
| _ _ _|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ |
| R3C2 | R3C3 | R3C4 | R3C5 | R3C6 |
| _ _ _|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ |
| R4C2 | R4C3 | R4C4 | R4C5 | R4C6 |
| _ _ _|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ |
| R5C2 | R5C3 | R5C4 | R5C5 | R5C6 |
| _ _ _|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ __|_ _ _ |
```

and on the next scroll it will change like,

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
| R1C3 | R1C4 | R1C5 | R1C6 | R1C7 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ | _ _ _|
| R2C3 | R2C4 | R2C5 | R2C6 | R2C7 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ | _ _ _|
| R3C3 | R3C4 | R3C5 | R3C6 | R3C7 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ | _ _ _|
| R4C3 | R4C4 | R4C5 | R4C6 | R4C7 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ _ |_ _ _ | _ _ _|
| R5C3 | R5C4 | R5C5 | R5C6 | R5C7 |
|_ _ _ | _ _ _|_ _ __|_ _ _ | _ _ _|
```

Could you please suggest how to do this using jquery and slider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in more than one way: shifting the table inside a div that makes use of overflow, adding and removing data to and from the table, or what I opted for, showing and hiding specific columns.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <table id="table-1" class="datatable">
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.datatable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: .5em 1em;
}

.datatable tbody {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.datatable tbody tr td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: .2em .4em;
}

td.hide {
  display: none;
}

#slider {
  width: 280px;
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var tData = [
  ["R1C1", "R1C2", "R1C3", "R1C4", "R1C5", "R1C6", "R1C7", "R1C8", "R1C9"],
  ["R2C1", "R2C2", "R2C3", "R2C4", "R2C5", "R2C6", "R2C7", "R2C8", "R2C9"],
  ["R3C1", "R3C2", "R3C3", "R3C4", "R3C5", "R3C6", "R3C7", "R3C8", "R3C9"],
  ["R4C1", "R4C2", "R4C3", "R4C4", "R4C5", "R4C6", "R4C7", "R4C8", "R4C9"],
  ["R5C1", "R5C2", "R5C3", "R5C4", "R5C5", "R5C6", "R5C7", "R5C8", "R5C9"]
];

$(function() {
  var $t = $("#table-1");
  var maxCol = 5;
  var cell = 0;
  // Populate the table
  $.each(tData, function(k1, v1) {
    // Create Rows
    var $row = $("<tr>", {
      id: "row-" + (k1 + 1),
      class: "row"
    });
    $.each(v1, function(k2, v2) {
      if (k2 < maxCol) {
        $("<td>", {
          class: "show col col-" + (k2 + 1),
          id: "cell-" + cell++
        }).html(v2).appendTo($row);
      } else {
        $("<td>", {
          class: "hide col col-" + (k2 + 1),
          id: "cell-" + cell++
        }).html(v2).appendTo($row);
      }
    });
    $row.appendTo($t);
  });

  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: tData[0].length - maxCol,
    value: 0,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      var i = ui.value + 1;
      var m = ui.value + maxCol;
      // Hide all
      $(".show").toggleClass("show hide");
      // Show just specific columns based on slider value
      for (i; i <= m; i++) {
        $(".col-" + i).removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3osy7fvh/

Comment: Slider example vs using Overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3osy7fvh/12/

Comment: Dude. Excellent. I will try to fine tune little bit similar to jqGrid. Instead of hiding the td, those td's data has to be replaced. If you have time, kindly go through the jqGrid paramquery. While there are more number of columns, during the slider dragging, there is a delay in rendering the data. It has been overcome in jqGrid.